# Where does the architectural term "planta" come from?

Tags: significado, etimologia

The best I can think of is that plants are close to the ground and a "planta" is, from what I understand, a ground-level architectural plan, but that's just a shot in the dark. Aulete usually would help with origination but, in this case, it doesn't.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks as though it ultimately comes from the sole of your foot!

An architectural **planta** is a floor plan. My Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa (DACL) says *planta* in all its meanings comes from the Latin word, well, [*planta*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/planta#Latin), which meant a plant; a shot, twig, or sprout; and the sole of the foot. Now this doesn’t help much. The best dictionary for etymology I know of is the big Houaiss, but I don't have one yet.

I think the answer lies with the verb **plantar**. *Plantar* means of course to plant a tree or flower so that they can grow roots into the soil. But according to the DACL it also means to firmly set something onto or into the ground, such as pitching a tent, driving stakes into the ground, and laying foundation stones. These days we’d say *montar* a tent, *cravar, espetar* stakes, and *assentar* foundation stones, so *plantar* in this latter sense is probably old use, which is what we’re looking for here.

Now, to lay the foundations of a building you’d traditionally drive stakes into the ground (**plantar estacas**) and connect them with ropes or maybe poles to mark the boundaries of the foundation trenches. And then you’d lay stones (**plantar pedras**) in those trenches. So you’d make the actual **planta** or floor plan on a 1-to-1 scale on the ground. See [this](http://www.google.pt/imgres?imgurl=http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-Odex3unKx5w/U-lscJTeHzI/AAAAAAAAALU/I4hsPFNgAR4/s1600/IMG_3648.JPG&imgrefurl=http://casarecantodaterra.blogspot.com/2014/08/02052014-o-primeiro-desafio-foi.html&h=1066&w=1600&tbnid=XUCKBeqSPUoBnM:&docid=Ryl0xkO-7ymeeM&ei=AqIHVrSYLoKfabOnkbAM&tbm=isch&ved=0CFQQMygsMCxqFQoTCLSh2r7flsgCFYJPGgods1MExg) and [this](http://masatocollector.blogspot.pt/2015/07/projeto-minha-casa-pt-05-alicerce-12.html) and [this](http://www.jornalarquitectos.pt/futebol-para-a-esperanca/). I’m in speculative mode here, so you draw your own conclusion. But I’ll just add that forming the word *planta* from *plantar* in these senses would be very natural. Compare *conta* and *contar* (counting things), *conto* and *contar* (stories), *fala* and *falar*, and so on and on.

After all this I looked up the etymology of the French equivalent, and it looks as though the speculation above may be on the right track. My Hachette Pratique du Français says **plan** (*planta, floor plan*) comes from **plant** in the old sense of “assiette d’un édifice” (original quotation marks), which sounds like the plate (thing you eat from) of a building. And in *assiette* we have only *assiette d’une route*, plate of a road, which is the surface necessary for the construction of a road. The modern French *plant* also means the piece of ground planted with trees. Wiktionnaire says [*plan*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plan), non 2 ([noun 2, the relevant one](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/plan#Nom_commun_2)), was originally *plant*, our old friend the “plate of a buiding”, which was formed by removing *er* from the verb [*planter*](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/planter#fr). Now *planter* has all the relevant meanings of the Portuguese [*plantar*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/plantar). So it looks as though *plant*, and most likely *panta*, originally meant the surface where you'd "plant" the building, and came later to mean a drawing of such place.

Both *planter* and *plantar* come from Latin *plantare*, which means to press into the ground with the sole of your foot (*sola ou planta do pé* in Portuguese). So Tchrist was right after all.

Comment: My instinctive guess is that rather than being relating to the verb for planting things that it is instead more connected to the third Latin sense about the flat part of your foot, and in general connected to flat things or ones lying in a plain. Speaking of flats, it might do to have a question about *planta, piso, andar* nuances.

Comment: My instinctive guess is... see my new argument.